# BukkitRunnable gives me a NPE

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Basically, this code works as I need it to, perfectly fine, however, If I move even the slightest bit or get out of the water, my console gets SPAMMED with NPE's... What have I done wrong with my code? What I'm trying to do is, if a player is in a specific location, inside of water, it will start a countdown, in this case, of 5 seconds. And after the 5 seconds, it's meant to say "Testing", etc. That part works, just not when I move or step out of the water. And yes, I'm aware that the code is sloppy and a bunch of junk but I don't want to create a whole class for cuboid for just one event.

```
private HashMap<UUID, Integer> afkCountdown;
private HashMap<UUID, BukkitRunnable> afkCountdownTask;

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerMoveEvent(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        afkCountdown = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
        afkCountdownTask = new HashMap<UUID, BukkitRunnable>();

        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        int x = 52;
        int y = 80;
        int z = 255;
        int x1 = 72;
        int y1 = 100;
        int z1 = 275;
        Location l1 = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("Void"), x, y, z);
        Location l2 = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("Void"), x1, y1, z1);
        Location loc = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("Void"), p.getLocation().getBlockX(), p.getLocation().getBlockY(), p.getLocation().getBlockZ());
        if (p.getWorld().equals(loc.getWorld())) {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(e.getTo()).getBlock().isLiquid()) {
                if (loc.getX() > l1.getX() && loc.getX() < l2.getX()) {
                    if (loc.getY() > l1.getY() && loc.getY() < l2.getY()) {
                        if (loc.getZ() > l1.getZ() && loc.getZ() < l2.getZ()) {
                            if (!afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                                afkCountdown.put(p.getUniqueId(), 5);
                                afkCountdownTask.put(p.getUniqueId(), new BukkitRunnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        afkCountdown.put(p.getUniqueId(), afkCountdown.get(p.getUniqueId()) - 1);
                                        if (afkCountdown.get(p.getUniqueId()) == 0) {
                                            p.sendMessage("Testing");
                                            afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                                            afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                                            afkCountdown.put(p.getUniqueId(), 5);
                                        } else if (!afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                                            cancel();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                afkCountdownTask.get(p.getUniqueId()).runTaskTimer(plugin, 20, 20);
                            } else {
                                return;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                                afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                                afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                            } else {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                            afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                            afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                        afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                        afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                    afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                    afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you [edit] your question to show your error ?

Comment: [03:46:58] [Server thread/WARN]: [TestPlugin] Task #1789 for TestPlugin v1.0 generated an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null @Elikill58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have multiple things to say about this code :

1. The value of `e.getTo()` will never be null. So the `Objects.requireNonNull` code is a useless import.
2. You get multiple time the same world instance with `Bukkit.getWorld("Void")`, but only one time is better.
3. Instead of create Location's object, you can check directly the `x/y/z` values that are given just before.
4. For the issue :

When you left liquid, all task will remove the value linked with the player's uuid. So, you will not be able to get id with `afkCountdown.get()` or `afkCountdownTask.get()`. To fix it, you should use `afkCountdown.getOrDefault(p.getUniqueId(), 0)`.

5. For timers, you never stop already started timer. So, your server with crash because of overflow. When you do `afkCountdownTask.remove()` you should do :

```java
BukkitRunnable task = afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId()); // return the removed one, or null if nothing removed
if(task != null) // if was existing
   task.cancel(); // cancel task
```

6. You are creating and resetting hashmap EACH move with `afkCountdown = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>()`. You should do it only one time.

Finally, this is the code that I propose to fix everything :

```java
private final HashMap<UUID, Integer> afkCountdown = new HashMap<>();
private final HashMap<UUID, BukkitRunnable> afkCountdownTask = new HashMap<>();

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMoveEvent(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    int x = 52;
    int y = 80;
    int z = 255;
    int x1 = 72;
    int y1 = 100;
    int z1 = 275;
    Location loc = e.getTo();
    if (p.getWorld().getName().equals("Void")) {
        if (loc.getBlock().isLiquid()) {
            if (loc.getX() > x && loc.getX() < x1) {
                if (loc.getY() > y && loc.getY() < y1) {
                    if (loc.getZ() > z && loc.getZ() < z1) {
                        if (!afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                            afkCountdown.put(p.getUniqueId(), 5);
                            afkCountdownTask.put(p.getUniqueId(), new BukkitRunnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    int amount = afkCountdown.getOrDefault(p.getUniqueId(), 0) - 1;
                                    afkCountdown.put(p.getUniqueId(), amount);
                                    if (amount <= 0) {
                                        p.sendMessage("Testing");
                                        afkCountdown.put(p.getUniqueId(), 5);
                                    } else if (!afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                                        cancel();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            afkCountdownTask.get(p.getUniqueId()).runTaskTimer(Main.getInstance(), 20, 20);
                        }
                        return; // don't want to remove, so end method now
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
        afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
        BukkitRunnable task = afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
        if(task != null)
            task.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm on 1.17.1

And now I get this error with the "changed" code;

https://pastebin.com/SafnXjbz

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.HashMap.containsKey(Object)" because "this.afkCountdown" is null

Comment: did you well change the full code, including hashmap declaration ?

Comment: This event is in my event handler, not my main.java.

Comment: And yes, I replaced everything with the updated code.

Comment: Shouldn't I add a else statement after 
```if (afkCountdown.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
            afkCountdown.remove(p.getUniqueId());
            BukkitRunnable task = afkCountdownTask.remove(p.getUniqueId());
            if(task != null)
                task.cancel();
        }```

Comment: for, it's not necessary. Just, here the variable is well declared so it can't be null. Also, I'm talking about variable OUTSIDE of the method (hasmpap). And that's literally impossible because I put them as final (can't be changed) and there is an instant declaration

Comment: Yes, I also included the hashmap out of the method

Comment: Seems like the code doesn't work at all anymore, not even in the water.

Comment: yes the error is at the beginning, before starting timer. So after fixing this NPE it will be fine. But such as the code in my answer is working, and the showed error is not possible, I suggest you to check if I made another change between the time you copy/paste and now

Comment: Actually, I don't see the code for me actually getting the hashmap. I have a hashmap stored but I don't have the part in my code to get it.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure that's the issue. I deleted the wrong 2 lines, and deleted your 2 lines for the hashmap ahahahha

Comment: Ah yes, that is satisfaction at its best. I appreciate your assistance. This code is valid and working for version 1.17.1 as well.